# Multiplying a table with constants

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table with coordinates `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}` that I want to multiply with a separate constant for `x` and one for y so: `{{a,b},{a,b}}`. (basically I rasterize a set of lines and then calculate the lines back) I have tried most of the suggestions that I found here on this forum and in the Documentation Center, but I cannot seem to find a correct and elegant solution.
In (test) code:

```
edge = 5 
vxstep = 0.01 
voffsetbottom = 10 
vspace = 5 
vystep = 0.0705 
vlength = 100 
vnumcell = 6
myList = Table[{
    {Round[vedge/vxstep], Round[(voffsetbottom + ii*vspace)/vystep]}, 
    {Round[(vlength - vedge)/vxstep], Round[(voffsetbottom +ii*vspace)/vystep]}
   }, {ii, 1, vnumcell}];
myList // TableForm  
myList *= {{vxstep, vystep},{vxstep,vystep}} (*this is what I'd like, but does not work*)`
```

Does anyone have suggestions how to make this multiplication work? Thanks!

Comment: First you should post your code in Mathematica notations to simplify our work to help you.I suggest that you take a tour and have a look at the rules. Second, it is not quite clear what do you want to obtain. Starting with `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}` do you have in mind to get `{{a*x1,b*y1},{a*x2,b*y2}}`?

Comment: `Map[Times[#, {a, b}] &, {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, {-2}]`?

Comment: `{{a*x1,b*y1},{a*x2,b*y2}}` is indeed wat I want to achieve. By te way, the code above is mathematica code, Except for the last line it runs perfectly. I'll give your suggestion a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
myList = Map[# {vxstep, vystep} &, myList, {2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Its actually a tad faster to map at the top level: `Map[# {{vxstep, vystep}, {vxstep, vystep}} &, myList, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you. In the end I had to tweak the code a little to:

`myList := Map[# {vxstep, vystep} &, myList, {2}]`

in order to avoid protected tag issues in a dynamic module. But the script is running smoothly now!